# PHP MySQL Show Grouped & Tag Duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a single Database that has a Table that looks like:

```
ID | FNAME | LNAME | DATE
```

Some rows have duplicate first/last names and I need to be able to detect they're duplicates and when I show them as a list, to show the number.

I need to make the output like so:

```
First Name (FNAME) / Last Name (LNAME) | Duplicate? Dupe #
```

My DB Connection looks like:

```
$query = "SELECT 
            FNAME,
            LNAME, 
            COUNT(LNAME) AS TOTAL
          FROM user_list
          GROUP BY LNAME";
```

PHP Code looks like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
 echo $row['FNAME'] . " / " . $row['FNAME']. " | ". $row['TOTAL'];
 echo "<br />";
}
```

I can't seem to group everything and show all of the queries as well count/show the Total.

So I need it to look like:

TOM / SMITH | 1
MIKE / ROBS | 1
TOM / SMITH | 2

So... If 2+ entries exist, it shows each entry and the entry it appears in the Database.

Comment: you need to group every fields you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the output to be like:

```
TOM / SMITH | 1
MIKE / ROBS | 1
TOM / SMITH | 2
```

Then that indeed is very convoluted.  But I think it can be done, even if trying it all in one-ish SQL statement.

Assuming you want them in some other order other than the names (where all the TOM SMITHs appear together), then you may need to add a unique ID field, and I will assume you want to sort by this ID field as well.  Then you could have something like this:

```
SET @name_count := 0, @prev_name := '';
SELECT FNAME, LNAME, namecount FROM user_list AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ID,
        (@name_count := IF(@prev_name = CONCAT(FNAME, ' ', LNAME), @name_count+1, 1)) AS namecount,
        (@prev_name := CONCAT(FNAME, ' ', LNAME)) AS prevname
    FROM (SELECT * FROM user_list ORDER BY FNAME ASC, LNAME ASC) AS tmp
    ) AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC;
```

Notes:

1. The SQL variables @name_count and @prev_name does depend on the order of the select statement, thus the inner ORDER BY.
2. The inner subquery sorts by the name, and assigns an incremental ranking to each name, starting over at 1 when it encounters a new name.
3. Note that `(@prev_name := ...)` does have to be listed after `(@name_count := IF(@prev_name = ..., ..., ...)`, or else it would assign prev_name first before it assigns name_count per each row, causing @prev_name to always equal the current name.
4. The inner SQL assigns the "rank" to each name instance, and the outer SQL will display them in the original order.
5. The part of `FROM (SELECT * FROM user_list ORDER BY FNAME ASC, LNAME ASC) AS tmp` does not have to be a subquery.  It can be `FROM user_list ORDER BY FNAME ASC, LNAME ASC`.  But I noticed in some cases, depending on the `ORDER BY` you use, especially if more than one field, it could cause some unexpected ordering.  So that is why I placed that table as another subquery - so it can do the name ordering first and correctly, and then do the ranking.
6. You may have to run it as two separate queries in your PHP. One query being `SET @name_count := 0, @prev_name := '';` and the other query being the rest of the string. If you try to put the whole string as one query in PHP, it will try to treat it as one query in most cases. In phpMyAdmin or in the mysql console, it would recognize it as two separate queries.

The other way to do this is just to do the counting in PHP instead of MySQL, where as you traverse the output, you keep an array of the last count of that name, and increment the count as the name comes up.

Comment: Only issue is, it does the count but I need it to output like:

TOM / SMITH | 1
MIKE / ROBS | 1
TOM / SMITH | 2

So... If 2+ entries exist, it shows each entry and the entry it appears in the Database.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much!


But my only issue now is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT FNAME, LNAME, namecount FROM user_list AS t1 INNER JOIN ( ' at line 2... 

Your code is beyond me, so I am not even sure where to go from here...

Comment: Sorry, you may have to run it as two separate queries in your PHP.  One query being `SET @name_count := 0, @prev_name := '';` and the other query being the rest of the string.  If you try to put the whole string as one query in PHP, it will try to treat it as one query in most cases.  In phpMyAdmin or in the mysql console, it would recognize it as two separate queries.